# What are these faux tiles actually called?

Tags: ceiling

I have some sections of my ceiling that contain these faux tiles, made of some kind of cheap wood (feels half way between cork and particle board). Each sheet is about 4ft by 4ft and has 4 tiles on them (2x2).

Any clue what these are called?

[image: As they look on the ceiling]

[image: Removed, front][image: Removed, rear]

Comment: I don't think these are acoustic tiles.

Comment: It looks like MDF that someone has carved a pattern into using a router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's "[hardboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardboard)" or "fiberboard" (MDF/HDF), sometimes also called Masonite for external (siding) applications. It's pressed wood fiber. It offers great uniformity and strength in dry conditions.

A search for "[decorative fiberboard panels](https://www.google.com/search?q=fiberboard%20decorative%20panels&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1019US1019&sxsrf=AJOqlzUSlRJOG7IKUB8iXgu1jKmakXCbQw:1677084730183&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhxua8y6n9AhW3CjQIHTFlDvsQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA)" yields useful results.